# When page load css load after second. Why?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

controller: test.php

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Test extends CI_Controller 
    {
        function __construct() 
        {
            parent :: __construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('url')); 
        }
        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('index');          
        }
    }
```

view: index.php

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>bootstrap</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        ..........content..........

        <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using codeigniter framework to show index file. When the page loads, html code are showing fine. But after loading all the js and css files the page breaks. I have included css files on top and js files at the bottom of the page.

Please anyone help me fixing this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Share the relevant codes please

Comment: Have you set the base url in config.php you need to also make sure your assets folder located out side application

Comment: yes, I have set base url in config.php and also assests folder located out side application.

Comment: Please add your code which you have done till now

Comment: please visit my edit code

Comment: please shared your folder structure for css ans jquery file and config.php file.

Comment: folder structure of css is http://localhost/company/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css similarly for js http://localhost/company/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js and In config.php file I have change only in base url i.e http://localhost/company/ and $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\=,&()';

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing you do in this case is to view your HTML Source in your browser to "eyeball" ( See ) the actual generated paths.

Right Mouse Click on your page and select View Source or press F12 and view the HTML depending upon your browser...

I am guessing you need to add a trailing / in your $config['base_url'] So try

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/company/'; // Trailing / required
```

Or you can do this... **leaving your $config['base_url']; as it is**

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('/resources/css/style.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

If you do add the trailing / to your $config['base_url'] you can use...

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('resources/css/style.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Make a decision and stick to it.

This is only one possible suggestion but something to look into.